# Can't get EF Code First to work on SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-2012, code-first

I have tried the solutions mentioned in all the existing questions, but none of them work for me. When I run my application (runs with no errors), and go and check the SQLExpress Database (through SQL Management Studio), I can see that **no tables have generated from my Code First classes**.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="BSContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=BSDomain; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am on Win 8 Pro 64x, and using VS 2012 along with SQL Express 2012. And here is my BSContext code:

```
public class BSContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

And in my application_start() I have the following:

```
Database.SetInitializer<BSContext>(new EventInitializer());
```

And the code for the EventInitializer is as follows:

```
public class EventInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BSContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(BSContext context)
    {
        // Seed Code
    }
}
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: how is your derived DbContext named ? It's got to be the same as your connection name `BSContext` - or make sure you're not defining the connection/name in the constructor (like `:base("...")`. It's most likely the connection issue. Your EF/CF uses one, you think it's something else.

Comment: Expanded Question with more info.

Comment: what's else in your .config ? provider, factory, db initializer etc.

Comment: Here is the [whole web.config](http://pastebin.com/N14Z4k0T).

Comment: What happens if you try to use the Context?  (e.g. var context = new BSContext();  context.Authors.ToList();)

Comment: I get `nulls` So `context.Authors.ToList();` returns `null`.

Comment: I'd suggest try and make a small console test, minimal - that repros what you have, if it does you can post it full - if it doesn't you know where to look for diffs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate please. When I use the localdb connection string, the app works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was simply because I was using the following format for my ID fields:

```
private int AuthorID { get; set; }
```

When I should have been using:

```
private int AuthorId { get; set; }
```

All works now !

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your Application_Start() method in Global.asax.

```
System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BSContext>());
```

This will force the application to create the DB every time your run the app, so don't leave it in there obviously!

Comment: Q expanded. As you can see, I have the DropCreateAlways on the Initializer class.